# How can I get a vscode url to work in a Plotly treemap

Tags: visual-studio-code, plotly

In the below treemap each box has two href's, one is `http://` and one is `vscode://`. The vscode link works in a plain HTML file, but does not work here. How can I put `vscode://` links in my treemap?

```
import plotly.express as px

TEMPLATE="""
%{label}<br>
Link1: <a href='http://google.com'>google</a>
Link2: <a href='vscode://file/somefile>somefile</a>
"""

def create_treemap():
    names = ['parent', 'child-1', 'child-2']
    ids = [1, 2, 3]
    parents = [None, 1, 1]
    values = [10, 5, 5]

    fig = px.treemap(names=names, ids=ids, parents=parents, values=values,
                    branchvalues='total', title="My Treemap")
    fig.update_traces(texttemplate=TEMPLATE)
    return fig

create_treemap().write_html("test.html")
```

My guess is plotly or SVG in general exposes `http` links as a special case, but does not expose `vscode://` links?